# Is it possible to create SSRS reports inside a react application?

Tags: reactjs, reporting-services

As the title reads, I'm trying to figure out how I would implement SSRS reporting inside a ReactJS application.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I've looked into embedding Power BI reports into my React application, however I would prefer to use SSRS as it is free (I'm using SQL Server).

My current approach is to gather the reporting service data from the client (filters, report type, etc.), build the report from the server side, then send the report to the client as a pdf.  I would much rather integrate SSRS into my application if possible however.

**Edit**

I'm aware of Power-BI, however I would prefer to use SSRS as it is free with my edition of SQL Server.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-React ?

Comment: No I haven't, thank you for pointing this out to me.

Comment: @Mini it would appear that the project has not been fully integrated to work with react.  It also does not show up in npm as documented in one of their issues shown here https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-React/issues/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest integration for SSRS is using the URL Access API.  You can generate a URL that calls your SSRS Report Server passing report parameter values and output format parameters.  I'm no expert in React but the integration of a URL should be easy for any web dev tool/framework.

It assumes you already have a working SSRS server with reports published to it - this is a useful step anyway for testing/debugging.

Here's the best starting point for the SSRS URL Access API doco:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Currently there aren't any options to only render SQL Reporting Services Reports for JS Frameworks, unless you want to paid a licence to have access to a private libraries.

There are a few libraries in Nuget packages, but only works for .NET and .NET Core web applications like Alan Juden ReportViewer, link:   [Alan Juden ReportViewer](https://github.com/alanjuden/MvcReportViewer)